# Where to ask "Is this right?" question of a brief 10 lines text?

Tags: discussion

It's a text for the dedication and aknowledgements sections of my thesis.

Thanks

Comment: If you ask here, I'll answer you myself: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin And if you have specific questions about parts you think are right or wrong, you can ask them on http://ell.stackexchange.com or here, as appropriate.

Comment: Note that "or here" in the last sentence is on [ELU Main site](http://english.stackexchange.com/), rather than Meta, where this question has ended up. As you're aware, neither ELL nor ELU does proofreading, although Chat is available for that.

Answer (score 6):

Since @Andrew only posted this as a comment, but imho it represents all and everything that really needs to be said, I'll post it as an upvoteable answer...

> ***neither ELL nor ELU does proofreading, although Chat is available for that***

---

(Okay, I *did* have something else to say...) Very likely this issue has been addressed in ELU Meta before, so the current question may well get closed as a duplicate. But the question *title* is so succinct it's useful to have around so future visitors can easily find it as a way in to any discussion.